# Impersonation via Web API in MSCRM not working in different environments

Tags: dynamics-crm, impersonation, dynamics-crm-2016, dynamics-crm-webapi

We are trying achieve impersonation in Dynamics CRM via Web API. I am successfully able to impersonate in Dev & Test environment, but the same code is not working in Model & Prod environment.

On some debugging we found out that MSCRM Web API on Model & Prod environment is not taking request Header "MSCRMCalledID" into account, which used for impersonation.

Is there any server setting related to this?

Comment: CRM is On Premise 2016(Ver:- 8.1)

Comment: Can you show what code you are using to perform the impersonation?